# applications of Lie theory in Riemannian geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Basically what the title says. Can you give an important use of lie groups/algebras in Riemannian geometry ?

Comment: Gauge theory, symmetric spaces uses heavily Lie groups.

Comment: Riemannian geometry is an example of a Cartan geometry. Loosely a Riemannian manifold looks locally like a homogeneous space (in this case Euclidean space). Put another way, the orthonormal frame bundle is a principal $O(n)$-bundle and we have a special $O(n)$-connection (the Levi-Civita).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theory of symmetric spaces. A Riemmanian manifold is called symmetric if for every $p$ there exist an isometry $I_p$, which is involutive $I_p^2= Id$, fixes $p$ and such that $p$ is an isolated point of the set of fixed points of $I_p$. The classification of symmetric spaces (Elie Cartan) gives you the complete list of such spaces (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space). For instance $G/K$ where $G$ is a semi-simple Lie group, $K$ a maximal compact subgroup is a symmetric space.